# What is the output of the below Scala code snippet?

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Why do I get the output of the below Scala code snippet as `List((), (), (), ())` :

```
val ans1 = for(i3 <- 1 to 4) yield {
 if (i3 % 2 == 0)
  i3
}
```

I tried the below :

```
val ans1 = for(i3 <- 1 to 4) yield {
if (i3 % 2 == 0)
i3
}
```

Expected:
`List(2,4)`

Comment: Just use `fitler`

Comment: The answers explain correctly why you get what you get. Here is one possible way to rewrite it to return what you want: `for { i3 <- 1 to 4 if i3 % 2 == 0 } yield i3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `thenExpr` and `elseExpr` have type `A` then `if (condition) thenExpr else elseExpr` has type `A` too.

If `thenExpr` and `elseExpr` have different types then `if ...` has their supertype.

If `elseExpr` is omitted then `if (condition) thenExpr` is a shorthand for `if (condition) thenExpr else ()`, where `()` has type `Unit`. So if `thenExpr` has type `Unit` then `if (condition) thenExpr` has type `Unit`, otherwise `if (condition) thenExpr` has a type, which is supertype of some type (the one of `thenExpr`) and `Unit` i.e. `Any` or `AnyVal`.

That's where those `()` are from and why the return type is `Seq[AnyVal]` rather than `Seq[Int]`.

Just don't omit `else` part. Also you can use standard methods `.map`, `.filter`. For-comprehensions are desugared into them.

As @Always_A_Learner and @Dima advised, you can try

```
val ans1 = for(i3 <- 1 to 4 if i3 % 2 == 0) yield i3
```